# How do I display the numeric value of a curve with Tooltip?

Tags: plotting, tooltip

Using `Tooltip`, is it possible to display the numeric value of the curve I've plotted using `Plot` and `PolarPlot`?

For example, is it possible to display the numeric y value of `Sin[x]` (or any other curve) with `Tooltip`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17545/display-function-value-on-hover  -- seems to be the same idea as @user6014's answer below.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34672/how-to-i-display-the-value-of-my-plot-function

Comment: See the "Get coordinates tool" [in the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InteractiveGraphicsPalette.html#119334373)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I did something like the following before, but maybe it was not for this site:

```
DynamicModule[{y0},
 EventHandler[
  Plot[Tooltip[Sin[x], Dynamic[y0]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
  "MouseMoved" :> (y0 = Sin@First@MousePosition["Graphics"]),
  ]]
```

*Update, per comment.*
Note that `MousePosition["Graphics"]` returns the coordinates of the mouse, not of a point on the graphics. It is triggered when the mouse is ***near*** the graphics, so it gives only a very rough approximation to the function value. One can take the x-coordinate of the mouse as given and calculate the y-coordinate from the function.  If the function is complicated, one might not want to copy the code into both arguments of `Tooltip`; I use `With` below so one needs only to type the function expression once. (There's a red syntax warning on the `x` inside `Dynamic`, because `Dynamic` is `HoldFirst` and `Plot` effectively uses `Block` to assign `x` a value; but it's just what we need here, since `Plot` finishes evaluating before `Dynamic` reaches the front end.)

```
With[{f = Sin[x]},
 Plot[
  Tooltip[f,
   Dynamic[f /. x -> First@MousePosition["Graphics"]]],
  {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
 ]
```

Bells & whistles:

```
With[{f = Sin[x]},
 DynamicModule[{x1, y1},
  EventHandler[
   Plot[
    f,
    {x, 0, 2 Pi},
    MaxRecursion -> 0,
    Epilog -> {Red, Dynamic@Tooltip[Point[{x1, y1}], {x1, y1}]},
    GridLines -> {
      Dynamic@If[NumericQ[x1], {x1}, None],
      Dynamic@If[NumericQ[y1], {y1}, None]}
    ],
   "MouseMoved" :> (
     x1 = First@MousePosition["Graphics", {x1, 0}];;
     y1 = f /. x -> x1)],
  Initialization :> (
    x1 = Pi; y1 = f /. x -> Pi)]]
```

Comment: for minimal functionality this is enough `Plot[Tooltip[Sin[x], Dynamic@MousePosition["Graphics"]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: @Kuba D'oh! Thanks! (You can answer with that, if you like. But I'm tempted to close as dupe....)

Answer (score 3):

Potential way to achieve this:

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
vals = Table[Tooltip[{x, Sin[x]}, Sin[x]], {x, 0, 10, .05}];
lp = ListPlot[vals, PlotStyle -> None];
Show[{pl, lp}]
```